# How to create snippets for a solution/project in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets, projects-and-solutions

It is possible to create global snippet that are available in all projects/solutions.

But what if I want to create a snippet that makes sense only in one solution and that evolves with the code in the solution because it uses APIs of that solution.  If I have 2 branches for that solution, the snippet might be different dependently on how the APIs have evolved so a global one will fail but one that is part of the solution will work.

So... How to create a snippet that is bound to a solution project in visual studio.

Comment: Code snippets are not meant to evolve with the code, creating new snippets would help you, but code snippets "evolving" is a sign of code that should make its way into project api/libraries